# ProcessPoolExecutor pass multiple arguments

Tags: python

ESPNPlayerFree

```
class ESPNPlayerFree:

def __init__(self, player_id, match_id, match_id_team):
...
```

teamList1:

```
 [('277906', 'cA2i150s81HI3qbq1fzi', 'za1Oq5CGHj3pkkXWNghG'), ('213674', 'cA2i150s81HI3qbq1fzi', 'za1Oq5CGHj3pkkXWNghG')]
```

Code

```
 with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=30) as executor:
    results = list(executor.map(ESPNPlayerFree, teamList1))
```

TypeError: `__init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'match_id' and 'match_id_team'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:**

With multiprocessing Pool you would use [starmap()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap) and it would use start `*` to unpack tuple to arguments

```
ESPNPlayerFree( *('277906', 'cA2i150s81HI3qbq1fzi', 'za1Oq5CGHj3pkkXWNghG') ) 
ESPNPlayerFree( *('213674', 'cA2i150s81HI3qbq1fzi', 'za1Oq5CGHj3pkkXWNghG') )
```

It seems `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` doesn't have `starmap()` so it sends it as one argument - `tuple`

```
ESPNPlayerFree( ('277906', 'cA2i150s81HI3qbq1fzi', 'za1Oq5CGHj3pkkXWNghG') ) 
ESPNPlayerFree( ('213674', 'cA2i150s81HI3qbq1fzi', 'za1Oq5CGHj3pkkXWNghG') )
```

and you would need to unpack it inside function

```
def __init__(self, data):
    player_id, match_id, match_id_team = data
```

Comment: I get this error now `AttributeError: 'ProcessPoolExecutor' object has no attribute 'startmap'`

Comment: Sorry, multiprocessing pool has [startmap()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap). It seems `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` doesn't have it and you will have to use `player_id, match_id, match_id_team = data`

Comment: Works perfectly, data is updating fast but now I get this error `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while getting the str of an object` Should I just increase the limit or there is a workaround?

Comment: I don't know what you do but do you have to use recursion ? Can't you do it without recursion using only some loop ?

Comment: I am not using recusion, it's just the `ESPNPlayerFree` class is huge and running it 15 times concurrently is throwing the error. I have increased the limit to 10k, no more recursion error but this error like before `concurrent.futures.process.BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.`

Comment: did you try to use less workers? OR better create new question and you will have more place to put full error message with full code.

Comment: okay, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59095905/brokenprocesspool-a-process-in-the-process-pool-was-terminated-abruptly-using

Answer (score 6):

Since `starmap` is not available, create a helper factory function for this:

```
def player_helper(args):
    return ESPNPlayerFree(*args)

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=30) as executor:
    results = list(executor.map(player_helper, teamList1))
```

Or make it into a `classmethod` for class `ESPNPlayerFree` if it makes more sense:

```
class ESPNPlayerFree:

...
    @classmethod
    def expand_args(cls, args):
        return cls(*args)


with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=30) as executor:
    results = list(executor.map(ESPNPlayerFree.expand_args, teamList1))
```

Answer (score 6):

According to source code of Executor.map:

```py
fs = [self.submit(fn, *args) for args in zip(*iterables)]
```

So you can have:

```py
executor.map(ESPNPlayerFree, player_id_list, match_id_list, match_id_team_list)
```

Comment: Source file link for reference:  https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/524a701d0742d2ae469771a065c62e41656a5dc7/Lib/concurrent/futures/_base.py#L608C66-L608C66